# Swift get public RSA key from private key?

Tags: swift, rsa, public-key

I use this RSA library for swift. https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA

Is there any way to export public RSA key from private key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the internal api calls, there is plenty of sample code and it’s literally 10 lines of code to create keys, obtain them from key chain and encrypt/decrypt data.

If you look in the library read me file, it tells you how to obtain a public key and then export it into various formats....

Comment: Thanks. let pubKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey.reference)

Comment: thats going to give you a SecKey, you need to do stuff to get the format you want (without the -----begin key ----  stuff etc)